# Way to keep over 65k TCP connect to a server

Tags: networking, load-balancing, haproxy

As a programmer and a newcomer to network and infrastructure,
I've developed a server program capable of handling over 100,000 connections concurrently.

During testing in a local network with 20,000 connections per client, everything worked smoothly:

```
           ┌──────┐
           │Router│
           └───┬──┘192.168.0.1/24
               │
    ┌──────────┴───────┬─────────┬─────────────┐
    │                  │         │             │
    │192.168.0.101     │         │             │
┌───┴──┐           ┌───┴───┐ ┌───┴───┐     ┌───┴───┐
│Server│           │Client1│ │Client2│ ... │Client5│
└──────┘           └───────┘ └───────┘     └───────┘
                 192.168.0.2             192.168.0.6
                           192.168.0.3
```

In this situation server programme will have sockets like:

```
SRC IP,      SRC Port, DST IP,        DST Port
192.168.0.2, 1       , 192.168.0.101, 8080
192.168.0.2, 2       , 192.168.0.101, 8080
...
192.168.0.2, 20000   , 192.168.0.101, 8080
192.168.0.3, 1       , 192.168.0.101, 8080
192.168.0.3, 2       , 192.168.0.101, 8080
...
192.168.0.3, 20000   , 192.168.0.101, 8080
...
192.168.0.6, 1       , 192.168.0.101, 8080
192.168.0.6, 2       , 192.168.0.101, 8080
...
192.168.0.6, 20000   , 192.168.0.101, 8080
```

But what happen clients over WAN?

```
     x      x             x
                 x
         Lots of Clients x
         x    x
    x          │ x      x    x
               │      x
             xx│
           xx  xx xx
          xx     x  x
         x  Internet x
          xxxxxxxxxxx
               │ 1.2.3.4
           ┌───┴──┐
           │Router│
           └───┬──┘192.168.0.1
               │
    ┌──────────┘
    │
    │192.168.0.101
┌───┴──┐
│Server│
└──────┘
```

I have no experience more than port forwarding,
so imageine let me do that. (1.2.3.4:8000 to 192.168.0.101:8000)

At this point, I foresee potential issues.
My concern is that the server may be limited to 65,535 sockets,
given that it can only see the router when connections come from the WAN.

```
SRC IP,      SRC Port, DST IP,        DST Port
192.168.0.1, 1       , 192.168.0.101, 8080
192.168.0.1, 2       , 192.168.0.101, 8080
...
192.168.0.1, 65355   , 192.168.0.101, 8080
```

I found some general solutions like

- Advanced router's NAT config of [Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/200608-Server-Load-Balancing-Using-Dynamic-NAT.html) or Juniper
- DNS RR (limited by a single public IP)
- Edit client to randomly choose range of ports, such as 1.2.3.4:8000 to :8080. (a challenging prospect)

1. Is what I'm assuming a real problem?
2. If I use HAProxy, should HAProxy replace router at all?
   Because if HAProxy still placed behind router, router to HAProxy is 1:1,
   then above problem still exist. Isn't it?
3. Any other possible solution for me except pluging WAN cable directly to server?

   Currently, I'm considering HAProxy for load balancing.
   By adding addresses to the interface,
   I could potentially connect up to 130,000 clients using commands like `ip addr add 192.168.0.102/24 dev eth0`.

Comment: Normally the source IP will be untouched by NAT.

Comment: `concern is that the server may be limited to 65,535 sockets` So It will fail on every system?

Comment: @vidarlo - there are different types of NAT. Source address is unchanged with D-NAT and masquerading only.

Comment: @symcbean true, but D-NAT/masquerade would be a workaround if both snat and dnat is used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My concern is that the server may be limited to 65,535 sockets, given that it can only see the router when connections come from the WAN.

Normally, destination NAT aka reverse NAT aka port forwarding doesn't change the *source* IP address or port number. That way, there's no such limitation.

Many load balancers also translate the source IP:port to one from their own pool to facilitate the backward connection. This depends on the configuration and can also be mitigated by increasing the pool, ie. number of (private / server-facing) IP addresses.

Generally, a server is only limited by their own resources[*1]. Additional limits may come from source NAT, bandwidth availability or general throughput limitations from in-path firewall, IDS/IPS etc.

A HA proxy may use a port substitution roughly similar to NAT, so the same logic applies.

[*1] In theory, each source IP address (possibly translated, from the server's perspective) can simultaneously open one connection per TCP port that it can use. Ephemeral ports vary by operating system between 49152-65535 to 1024-65535.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in IPv4 and IPv6, the sockets are identified by the IP address and port number. If all your traffic *appears* to be coming from the same IP address then you are limited to the number of ports. Indeed if your masquerading router is supporting multiple servers listening on the same port at different local addresses, then available ports will be shared between them.

The constraint is that a server is limited to 65535 connections per client IP address. And so is a client.

(actually less than 65535 as some of the ports are reserved - how many varies by OS).

But a host can have more than one IP address. Depending on your OS this may even be supported on a single NIC. It may require additional configuration to avoid asymmetric routing. Whether the masquerading in your router supports a large number of connections is a different question.

Most services require a significant amount of work to be done by the server - and its almost *always* better to have 2 smaller hosts handling a task than one large one. So this limit is rarely a constraint in the real world.

HAProxy does not nothing to resolve your issue here. Indeed it *enforces* the NAT constraint.